# Python IPify VPN Checker API KeyError

Tags: python, json, ip-address

I am trying to use https://vpn-proxy-detection.ipify.org, and I can't get it to work. How do i get the value "vpn" inside "proxy"

```
req2 = requests.get(url = VPNLink + IP)
data3 = req2.json()
print(data3)
VPN = data3[""]
print(VPN)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VPNChecker.py", line 47, in <module>
    VPN = data3["proxy.vpn"]
KeyError: 'proxy.vpn
```

---

This is the output from the API:

```
{"ip":"8.8.8.8","proxy":{"proxy":false,"vpn":false,"tor":false}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make it like so:

```
VPN = data3["proxy"]["vpn"]
```

But be aware that when your program does network stuff, you have to look out for exceptions (e.g. server not found, server is down, KeyError if there's no `proxy` or no `vpn`).